# Android: How to build and replace modified AOSP code

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source, stagefright

I am starting to work with stage fright frame work to implement hardware decoder in android prior to Jelly bean in my video conferencing application.
I have downloaded and built the android source code in Mac system. I am not clear with the whole idea of working with AOSP. And my questions are (with respect to stagefright framework)

1. Where can I find the libstagefright.so after AOSP build ?.
2. If I use the OMX codec in my class for decode, how should I link the libstagefright.so to native code of my application ? If I build my native code by copying the libstagefright.so and linking it via make file is that the way ?
3. How can I use it in my application ? If I load it via System.loadLibrary(" "), will it work ??

**UPDATE:**
I have tried the suggestion from Ganesh. But when I tried to build the project with NDK it is not taking the headers included as LOCAL_C_INCLUDES.

Here is my android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := custom_decoder

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)\includes \
                    frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/include \
                    frameworks/native/include/media/openmax \
                    frameworks/base/include/media/stagefright

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
                    libstagefright libstagefright_omx libstagefright_foundation libutils liblog

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := custom_decoder_jni.cpp custom_decoder.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

the error is shown from custom_decoder.h when it is reading the includes of AOSP.

```
 fatal error: DataSource.h: No such file or directory.
```

I haven"t included any AOSP .so in my project(as per Ganesh's suggestion in comment 2). Should I do that?

What else should I do to get it built......

Comment: `libstagefright` and OMX are available on all Android devices since Gingerbread, you don't need to build AOSP to use it.

Comment: @Alex Cohn Thank you for your reply. I am doing it via android ndk. To build the native code where I will be calling the OMXCodec apis, I need to include libstagefright.so no, since they are not exposed in ndk ? For that I did the AOSP build... Pls give me some corrections if my way is wrong........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific queries,

1. `libstagefright.so` is built and installed at `/system/lib`
2. I presume you are employing the `libstagefright.so` in native code. With this assumption, you don't have to copy. I presume you are building your module as a loadable library i.e. `.so` file. Hence, if you can identify the dependency on `libstagefright.so` through `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` as well as including the header files, it should be more than sufficient for building your module. Please refer to this [example of building a `FLAC` encoder](http://androidxref.com/4.4.3_r1.1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/codecs/flac/enc/Android.mk) where similar dependencies have been handled.
3. By application, if you are referring to a `Java` application which interacts with a `JNI` layer, then point 2 should be more than sufficient. However, if you are creating a native layer application, I would recommend you to follow [`stagefright` command line utility's `makefile`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.3_r1.1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/Android.mk).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried it and I have updated my question with my make file. Please suggest the errors...

Comment: @androkid.. The error is because you are not including `frameworks/av/include`. Also it is recommended to employ something like `$(TOP)/frameworks/av/include`. If this doesn't work, please try `$(TOP)/frameworks/av/include/media/libstagefright`. Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thanks for the spot response...I included the header like this #include <DataSource.h> (also tried #include "DataSource.h") But to get the same error...

Comment: @androkid..can you please join this room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55977/ganeshtalks

Comment: The header DataSource.h is at $(TOP)/frameworks/base/include/media/stagefright/ I have added that too..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55978/discussion-between-androkid-and-ganesh).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to rebuild `libstagefright.so` to use it in your app. You can `adb pull` the library from your device, or even from an emulator.

Please note that `libstagefright` communicates with many components in `/system/lib`, some of which are specific to SoC vendor (e.g. Qualcomm) or ODM (e.g. Samsung). Some uses of Stagefright may require *quirks* specific to device. This is why **[OpenMAX IL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMAX)** has not been officially exposed on Android. On the otehr hand, **[OpneMAX AL](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/openmaxal/index.html)** has been officially supported since November 2011.

At any rate, `libstagefright` cannot be directly accessed from Java. If you are looking for a Java solution for video communication, you should first look at the excellent [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) library.

The advantage of using `libstagefright` comes usually when you have you your native (C/C++) library that only has to be connected to an efficient codec.

Here is a nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16152074/192373) on a related question about Android hardware decoder.